# Java Do While Validation

Tags: java, arrays, validation, do-while

How do I change this while(true) into a do while so when the user enters a number they will be given back details but if they enter * the system will close.

```
while (true){
         System.out.print("Enter number: ");
         int option = keyboard.nextInt(); 
         out.writeInt(option);
```

Comment: You can't receive the '*' as an input if you are using `nextInt()`.

Comment: If I change it so the user enters -1, is this possible and how?

Comment: Yes, even easier. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
char option;
do {
         System.out.print("Enter number: ");
         option = keyboard.nextChar(); 
         out.writeChar(option);
} while (option != '*')
```

Comment: I believe he wanted the asterisk NOT to be printed

Comment: I need it to stay as an integer. is that possible?

Comment: You can't read an integer and then compare that integer to a '*'. but you should be able to see if it can be converted to an int, and print it if it could be an int.

Comment: If I change it so the user enters -1, is this possible and how?

Comment: Did you make `nextChar()` up?

Comment: Yes, I did make that up, because the focus of my response was on how to convert what he provided into a do..while loop. Since he didn't indicate what kind of an object keyboard was, I was free to assume it had a nextChar() method. If you wanted to check for a "-1", you'd have to read in a String object, and use the Equals method of the String to see if its "-1", or parse it into an Integer object, and test the value of the Integer against -1

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `nextLine()` or `next()` to receive the input and parse them accordingly:

```
do{
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    String str = keyboard.nextLine();
    int option = 0;
    if(str.matches"[0-9]+"){
        option = Integer.parseInt(str);
        System.out.println(option);
    }
    else if(str.equals("*"))
        System.exit(0);   //or use break; if you want to exit the loop
}while(whatever);         //whatever == true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to allow the user to input a String and then convert to int if possible, you can catch any errors and break out if the user enters a '*' character:

```
    import java.util.*;

    class MainInput{

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            int option;
            String input;

            do{
                 System.out.print("Enter number: ");
                 input = keyboard.nextLine();
                 try{
                    option = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    System.out.println("You entered the value: " + option);
                 }
                 catch(Exception ex) {
                     if (!input.equals("*")){
                         System.err.println("Invalid input, please enter numbers only.");
                    }
                 }
            }while(!input.equals("*"));
        }
    }
```

If you use an exit value like (-1), you can continue to process input with `nextInt()` and becomes even easier. You can do this with a simple do/while:

```
   import java.util.*;

    class MainInput{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            int option = 0;
            do{
                 System.out.print("Enter number: ");
                 option = keyboard.nextInt();
                 System.out.println("You entered the value: " + option);
            }while(option != -1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   do{
       System.out.print("Enter number: ");
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String str = sc.nextLine();

    }while(!str.equals("*"))
```

edit: if you want to play with numbers as integer or double. Just let me know and I'll add casted version as your needs.

```
    int number;
   do{
       System.out.print("Enter number: ");
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String str = sc.nextLine();
       number = Integer.parseInt(str);
    }while(!str.equals("*"))
```

now you have a integer `number`.

Comment: hi, i want to enter in an integer not a string how would this look?